# Trying to remove all occurances of a few patterns from a list

Tags: python

So I have a list, something like this:

`check = ['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29', '10.45.33.109/32', '10.202.1.113/32', '10.202.1.119/32', '10.202.1.122/32', '10.202.1.124/32', '10.202.1.126/32', '10.202.1.130/32', '10.202.1.132/32', '10.202.1.135/32', '10.202.1.136/32', '10.202.1.137/32', '10.202.1.139/32', '10.202.1.140/32', '10.202.1.141/32', '10.202.1.145/32', '10.202.1.146/32', '10.202.1.148/32', '10.202.1.149/32', '10.202.1.150/32', '10.202.1.151/32', '10.202.1.152/32', '10.202.1.154/32', '10.202.1.155/32', '10.202.1.156/32', '10.202.1.157/32', '10.202.1.158/32', '10.202.1.159/32', '10.202.1.160/32', '10.202.1.161/32', '10.202.1.162/32', '10.202.1.164/32', '10.202.1.165/32', '10.202.1.167/32', '10.202.1.168/32', '10.202.1.169/32', '10.202.1.170/32', '10.202.1.171/32', '10.202.1.172/32', '10.202.1.173/32', '10.202.1.174/32', '10.202.1.175/32', '10.202.1.176/32', '10.202.1.177/32', '10.202.1.178/32', '10.202.1.179/32', '10.202.1.180/32', '10.202.1.181/32', '10.202.1.182/32']`

I'm trying to remove all the elements containing any of the elements of this list:

`['/30', '/31', '/32']`

For some reason, the list is being partially trimmed down, and I cannot quite understand why.

My code:

```
y = 30

while y <=32:
    x.append('/'+str(y)) # To generate the list of elements
    y = y + 1



check = ['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29', '10.45.33.109/32', '10.202.1.113/32', '10.202.1.119/32', '10.202.1.122/32', '10.202.1.124/32', '10.202.1.126/32', '10.202.1.130/32', '10.202.1.132/32', '10.202.1.135/32', '10.202.1.136/32', '10.202.1.137/32', '10.202.1.139/32', '10.202.1.140/32', '10.202.1.141/32', '10.202.1.145/32', '10.202.1.146/32', '10.202.1.148/32', '10.202.1.149/32', '10.202.1.150/32', '10.202.1.151/32', '10.202.1.152/32', '10.202.1.154/32', '10.202.1.155/32', '10.202.1.156/32', '10.202.1.157/32', '10.202.1.158/32', '10.202.1.159/32', '10.202.1.160/32', '10.202.1.161/32', '10.202.1.162/32', '10.202.1.164/32', '10.202.1.165/32', '10.202.1.167/32', '10.202.1.168/32', '10.202.1.169/32', '10.202.1.170/32', '10.202.1.171/32', '10.202.1.172/32', '10.202.1.173/32', '10.202.1.174/32', '10.202.1.175/32', '10.202.1.176/32', '10.202.1.177/32', '10.202.1.178/32', '10.202.1.179/32', '10.202.1.180/32', '10.202.1.181/32', '10.202.1.182/32']

print(len(check))
s = []
for i in x:
    for j in check:
        if i in j:
            print("True")
            print(i)
            print(j)
            check.remove(j)

print(len(check))
print(check)
```

Any help is appreciated, since I'm stuck debugging this.

Instead of `if i in j`, I have also used `if i == j[-3:]`, also with the same partially trimmed result.

The result, just FYI:

['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29', '10.202.1.113/32', '10.202.1.122/32', '10.202.1.126/32', '10.202.1.132/32', '10.202.1.136/32', '10.202.1.139/32', '10.202.1.141/32', '10.202.1.146/32', '10.202.1.149/32', '10.202.1.151/32', '10.202.1.154/32', '10.202.1.156/32', '10.202.1.158/32', '10.202.1.160/32', '10.202.1.162/32', '10.202.1.165/32', '10.202.1.168/32', '10.202.1.170/32', '10.202.1.172/32', '10.202.1.174/32', '10.202.1.176/32', '10.202.1.178/32', '10.202.1.180/32', '10.202.1.182/32']

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to edit a list while iterating it. Instead of doing `check.remove` create a new list and do `newlist.append` for the records you want to keep.

Comment: @match I did try that, and the new list is the same as the trimmed list. 

the code I used: 

` if i not in j and j not in s:`
    `s.append(j)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will, you have a simple logical error because you are using 2 Iterations.
assuming that the list you have contain 100 ip, in this code you actually iterate through it 300 times.
but each time you checking just one value at a time

["/30", "/31", "/32"]

also if you removed an element from the list the iteration will continue on the next element and you will miss one, so the double iteration here will not work as intended.

you can simply use all conditions at once like...

```
check = ['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29', '10.45.33.109/32', '10.202.1.113/32', '10.202.1.119/32', '10.202.1.122/32', '10.202.1.124/32', '10.202.1.126/32', '10.202.1.130/32', '10.202.1.132/32', '10.202.1.135/32', '10.202.1.136/32', '10.202.1.137/32', '10.202.1.139/32', '10.202.1.140/32', '10.202.1.141/32', '10.202.1.145/32', '10.202.1.146/32', '10.202.1.148/32', '10.202.1.149/32', '10.202.1.150/32', '10.202.1.151/32', '10.202.1.152/32', '10.202.1.154/32', '10.202.1.155/32', '10.202.1.156/32', '10.202.1.157/32', '10.202.1.158/32', '10.202.1.159/32', '10.202.1.160/32', '10.202.1.161/32', '10.202.1.162/32', '10.202.1.164/32', '10.202.1.165/32', '10.202.1.167/32', '10.202.1.168/32', '10.202.1.169/32', '10.202.1.170/32', '10.202.1.171/32', '10.202.1.172/32', '10.202.1.173/32', '10.202.1.174/32', '10.202.1.175/32', '10.202.1.176/32', '10.202.1.177/32', '10.202.1.178/32', '10.202.1.179/32', '10.202.1.180/32', '10.202.1.181/32', '10.202.1.182/32']
s = []

for ip in check:
    if ("/30" not in ip) and ("/31" not in ip) and ("/32" not in ip):
        s.append(ip)

print(s)
```

or more combined code like this one will work too

```
check = ['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29', '10.45.33.109/32', '10.202.1.113/32', '10.202.1.119/32', '10.202.1.122/32', '10.202.1.124/32', '10.202.1.126/32', '10.202.1.130/32', '10.202.1.132/32', '10.202.1.135/32', '10.202.1.136/32', '10.202.1.137/32', '10.202.1.139/32', '10.202.1.140/32', '10.202.1.141/32', '10.202.1.145/32', '10.202.1.146/32', '10.202.1.148/32', '10.202.1.149/32', '10.202.1.150/32', '10.202.1.151/32', '10.202.1.152/32', '10.202.1.154/32', '10.202.1.155/32', '10.202.1.156/32', '10.202.1.157/32', '10.202.1.158/32', '10.202.1.159/32', '10.202.1.160/32', '10.202.1.161/32', '10.202.1.162/32', '10.202.1.164/32', '10.202.1.165/32', '10.202.1.167/32', '10.202.1.168/32', '10.202.1.169/32', '10.202.1.170/32', '10.202.1.171/32', '10.202.1.172/32', '10.202.1.173/32', '10.202.1.174/32', '10.202.1.175/32', '10.202.1.176/32', '10.202.1.177/32', '10.202.1.178/32', '10.202.1.179/32', '10.202.1.180/32', '10.202.1.181/32', '10.202.1.182/32']
x = ["/30", "/31", "/32"]
s = [j for j in check if not any(i in j for i in x)]
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .endswith()

Or .split(“/“) and test whether
final component is in the 30’s.

——

Print out repr() of the   string to verify there’s are no hidden, invisible, unprintable characters lurking within it, for example, a newline.
Repr stands for representation, and it will reveal such characters.

Comment: endswith() is giving me the same partially trimmed list. I am trying the split('/') method, will update if it works.

Comment: Edit: I did try split('/') and the resulting list is the same partially trimmed list :-(

Comment: repr() of all the items in the list revealed no hidden, invisible or unprintable characters lurking.

Answer (score 1):

just need to check last 3 character of string, use list slicing and check if it is present in filter keyword or not.

by overwriting check

```
>>> filtered = {'/30','/31','/32'}
>>> check[:] = [i for i in check if not(i[-3:] in filtered)]
>>> check
['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
x = [f"/{i}" for i in range(30, 33)] #Including 30, 31, 32

check = ['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29', '10.45.33.109/32', '10.202.1.113/32', '10.202.1.119/32',
         '10.202.1.122/32', '10.202.1.124/32', '10.202.1.126/32', '10.202.1.130/32', '10.202.1.132/32',
         '10.202.1.135/32', '10.202.1.136/32', '10.202.1.137/32', '10.202.1.139/32', '10.202.1.140/32',
         '10.202.1.141/32', '10.202.1.145/32', '10.202.1.146/32', '10.202.1.148/32', '10.202.1.149/32',
         '10.202.1.150/32', '10.202.1.151/32', '10.202.1.152/32', '10.202.1.154/32', '10.202.1.155/32',
         '10.202.1.156/32', '10.202.1.157/32', '10.202.1.158/32', '10.202.1.159/32', '10.202.1.160/32',
         '10.202.1.161/32', '10.202.1.162/32', '10.202.1.164/32', '10.202.1.165/32', '10.202.1.167/32',
         '10.202.1.168/32', '10.202.1.169/32', '10.202.1.170/32', '10.202.1.171/32', '10.202.1.172/32',
         '10.202.1.173/32', '10.202.1.174/32', '10.202.1.175/32', '10.202.1.176/32', '10.202.1.177/32',
         '10.202.1.178/32', '10.202.1.179/32', '10.202.1.180/32', '10.202.1.181/32', '10.202.1.182/32']

filtered_list = [i for i in check for j in x if j not in i]
print(filtered_list)
```

```bash
>>> ['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29', '10.92.145.25/29', '10.45.33.109/32', '10.45.33.109/32', '10.202.1.113/32', '10.202.1.113/32', '10.202.1.119/32', '10.202.1.119/32', '10.202.1.122/32', '10.202.1.122/32', '10.202.1.124/32', '10.202.1.124/32', '10.202.1.126/32', '10.202.1.126/32', '10.202.1.130/32', '10.202.1.130/32', '10.202.1.132/32', '10.202.1.132/32', '10.202.1.135/32', '10.202.1.135/32', '10.202.1.136/32', '10.202.1.136/32', '10.202.1.137/32', '10.202.1.137/32', '10.202.1.139/32', '10.202.1.139/32', '10.202.1.140/32', '10.202.1.140/32', '10.202.1.141/32', '10.202.1.141/32', '10.202.1.145/32', '10.202.1.145/32', '10.202.1.146/32', '10.202.1.146/32', '10.202.1.148/32', '10.202.1.148/32', '10.202.1.149/32', '10.202.1.149/32', '10.202.1.150/32', '10.202.1.150/32', '10.202.1.151/32', '10.202.1.151/32', '10.202.1.152/32', '10.202.1.152/32', '10.202.1.154/32', '10.202.1.154/32', '10.202.1.155/32', '10.202.1.155/32', '10.202.1.156/32', '10.202.1.156/32', '10.202.1.157/32', '10.202.1.157/32', '10.202.1.158/32', '10.202.1.158/32', '10.202.1.159/32', '10.202.1.159/32', '10.202.1.160/32', '10.202.1.160/32', '10.202.1.161/32', '10.202.1.161/32', '10.202.1.162/32', '10.202.1.162/32', '10.202.1.164/32', '10.202.1.164/32', '10.202.1.165/32', '10.202.1.165/32', '10.202.1.167/32', '10.202.1.167/32', '10.202.1.168/32', '10.202.1.168/32', '10.202.1.169/32', '10.202.1.169/32', '10.202.1.170/32', '10.202.1.170/32', '10.202.1.171/32', '10.202.1.171/32', '10.202.1.172/32', '10.202.1.172/32', '10.202.1.173/32', '10.202.1.173/32', '10.202.1.174/32', '10.202.1.174/32', '10.202.1.175/32', '10.202.1.175/32', '10.202.1.176/32', '10.202.1.176/32', '10.202.1.177/32', '10.202.1.177/32', '10.202.1.178/32', '10.202.1.178/32', '10.202.1.179/32', '10.202.1.179/32', '10.202.1.180/32', '10.202.1.180/32', '10.202.1.181/32', '10.202.1.181/32', '10.202.1.182/32', '10.202.1.182/32']
```

Usually its not a good idea to mutate a `list` while `iterating/looping` through it, also `list comprehension` is a bit faster than normal `for loops`
Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation, it made me aware of what I was doing wrong.
But the result is not what I want, I want something like:

`['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29']`

which I did get from one of the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

```
check = ['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29', '10.45.33.109/32', '10.202.1.113/32', '10.202.1.119/32', '10.202.1.122/32', '10.202.1.124/32', '10.202.1.126/32', '10.202.1.130/32', '10.202.1.132/32', '10.202.1.135/32', '10.202.1.136/32', '10.202.1.137/32', '10.202.1.139/32', '10.202.1.140/32', '10.202.1.141/32', '10.202.1.145/32', '10.202.1.146/32', '10.202.1.148/32', '10.202.1.149/32', '10.202.1.150/32', '10.202.1.151/32', '10.202.1.152/32', '10.202.1.154/32', '10.202.1.155/32', '10.202.1.156/32', '10.202.1.157/32', '10.202.1.158/32', '10.202.1.159/32', '10.202.1.160/32', '10.202.1.161/32', '10.202.1.162/32', '10.202.1.164/32', '10.202.1.165/32', '10.202.1.167/32', '10.202.1.168/32', '10.202.1.169/32', '10.202.1.170/32', '10.202.1.171/32', '10.202.1.172/32', '10.202.1.173/32', '10.202.1.174/32', '10.202.1.175/32', '10.202.1.176/32', '10.202.1.177/32', '10.202.1.178/32', '10.202.1.179/32', '10.202.1.180/32', '10.202.1.181/32', '10.202.1.182/32']

newlist = []
for n,item in enumerate(check):
    if not item.split("/")[-1] in ['30', '31', '32']: 
        newlist.append(item)
print(newlist)

# result
# ['10.92.145.17/29', '10.92.145.25/29']
```